# Cryptographic Services no responding

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

On our Win2012R2 server, every couple days we have the same issue happening causing the server no responding to login/logoff/shutdown, the only way we can do is to force to power off the server and reboot.

Here is the event

```
The following service has repeatedly stopped responding to service control requests: Cryptographic Services
Contact the service vendor or the system administrator about whether to disable this service until the problem is identified.
You may have to restart the computer in safe mode before you can disable the service.

A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the CryptSvc service
```

I ve been searching for solution for while and there is no fix I can find for this issue. The HP SPP has been applied and MS update is up-to-date.

How can I troubleshoot this Cryptographic Services issue?

Comment: did you got any further with this? i just had it on two separate windows 2012R2 Physical servers. both had the following updates pending install 4034681\4034672\4025333\4022717\Silver light 5.1.50907.0 G

Comment: No luck so far........Do you think because of silverlight update? I dont think I had silverlight installed on my server at all... I only install security updates

Comment: That's the list of hotfixes that are currently instaled on both servers (some of them have

Comment: Sorry for the above (sent before completing). That's the list of hotfixes that are currently installed on both servers https://pastebin.com/znE4Cwed  (the count is for if it's installed on one server or both). The two servers are cluster nodes (in separate clusters) running SQL always on. and it happen during network maintenance we did . that took one network card used for iSCSI down at a time (there's no exact time correlation for the port up-down to that event. around 10 min apart, but still suspiciously close to these events. )